# Is there any way to use callsFake with sinon spies?

Tags: testing, chai, sinon, spy, sinon-chai

I am trying to migrate from [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) to chai and Sinon. 
I expect we do something like this

```js
this.check = expect.spyOn(module, "method").andCall(function(dep) {
    return dep;
});
```

But I want this behavior with Chai and Sinon.

```js
 this.check = sinon.spy(module, "method")
```

But how do I get the `andCall` as I refer the docs and I guess `callsFake` cant be call with `spy`  and I don't really think this will have similar behavior with `stud`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
it('makes blue cheese', () => {
  const mySpy = sinon.spy()

  sinon.stub(module, 'method')
    .callsFake((...args) => {
      mySpy(...args)
      // Do other stuff here like return a value
      return 'blue cheese'
    })

  const testValue = module.method('hello', 'world')
  expect(testValue).to.eq('blue cheese')
  expect(mySpy).to.have.been.calledWith('hello', 'world')
})
```

This way of stubbing and calling a spy works in tests I've written using Sinon `8.1.1`.

I haven't tried the following, but here's an example of using `async`/`await` syntax:

```js
it('makes blue cheese async', async () => {
  const mySpy = sinon.spy()

  sinon.stub(module, 'method')
    .callsFake(async (...args) => {
      mySpy(...args)
      return 'blue cheese'
    })

  const testValue = await module.method('hello', 'world')
  expect(testValue).to.eq('blue cheese')
})
```

Comment: what if it is async?

Comment: You'd need to update the syntax to async/await, and make sure to await module.method when setting testValue. I've updated my answer to provide an example of where that syntax is sprinkled in